# how to convert string of decimal to list and mark items as max and min

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this string "1.2,3,4.6,7,8,23"  and I need to convert it to a list and to findout the min and max object in the list.

I tried

```
List<decimal> prices = item.arrKFD_Price.Split(',').Select(n => decimal.Parse(n)).ToList();
```

I now have a list of decimals and I can get the max or min by using

```
prices.Max() or prices.Min()
```

I need the data in the loop

```
foreach (var price in prices)
{
    sb.Append("<td>" + price + "</td>");//need to set color for max and min
}
```

I tried to create a list of objects

```
class myPrice{
    public decimal price{ get;set;}
    public bool IsMax{ get;set;}
    public bool IsMin{ get;set;}
}
```

and then used it in the split

```
List<myPrice> prices = item.arrKFD_Price.Split(',').Select(n => decimal.Parse(n)).ToList();`
```

and then maybe mark the object and use it in the loop

Comment: Can you reorder them? It would be easy enough to print them out in order and know mix and max.

Comment: no, the order is the order that i need to print them, it's not the order of value...

Comment: 1. Make list with identicator of posisition.
2. Then sort. 
3. Set min and max values on your structure
4. Sort by identicator
5. Print.

Answer (score 6):

Simply remember min and max:

```
double max = prices.Max();
double min = prices.Min();
```

Then in the loop use this information:

```
foreach (var price in prices)
{
    if(price == min) ...  // use color for min
    else if price == max) ... // use color for max
    else ... // use normal color
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `SortedSet<decimal>` instead which has a `Min` and `Max` property:

```
var prices = new SortedSet<decimal>("1.2,3,4.6,7,8,23".Split(',').Select(decimal.Parse));

foreach (var price in prices)
{
    bool isMin = price == prices.Min;
    bool isMax = price == prices.Max;
    // ...
}
```

But note that this collection does not accept duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<decimal> prices = item.arrKFD_Price.Split(',').Select(n => decimal.Parse(n)).ToList();

var max = prices.Max();
var min = prices.Min();

foreach (var price in prices)
{
    var s = String.format("<td {0}>{1}</td>", GetColor(min,max,price), price); 
    sb.Append(s.ToString());
}

// This gets the style for the td
private string GetColor(decimal min, decimal max, decimal p)
{
    if (p == min)
        return "class='min'";

    if (p == max)
        return "class='max'";

    return "";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

1. Make list with identicator of position.
2. Then sort.
3. Set min and max values on your structure
4. Sort by identicator
5. Print.